# Binet's differential equation yields a circular path

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Binet's equation is $$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}+(1-\frac{\lambda}{a^2v^2})u=0$$
I need to show that for $\lambda=a^2v^2$ path will be a circle.
For $\lambda=a^2v^2$ I have $$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}=0$$

Can you give me some hints what to do now?

Comment: Convert from Polar Coordinates to Rectangular! You are being fooled by the form of the second equation in your post.

Comment: What are Rectangular Coordinates? Cartesian maybe? I'm not sure if I know how to convert them. May you help me?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation).

Comment: Also, [check this](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/BinetsEquation.html).

Comment: I checked both but I am not sure what are you telling me to do. Maybe I should solve inverse problem?